# Can I put a CollaborativeString inside a custom type?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-realtime-api

I'm reading the Google Drive Realtime API documentation on [Building a Collaborative Data Model](https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/build-model).

I really like the way `gapi.drive.realtime.databinding.bindString` behaves.  It doesn't mess up your cursor placement when multiple people are typing in the same text box.  But it requires that you pass it a CollaborativeString.

But if you register a custom type, you have to use `gapi.drive.realtime.custom.collaborativeField` no matter what type of field you are defining, and you can't pass one of these to `bindString`.  In fact, the collaborativeField type does not appear to be documented anywhere, and inspecting it in the console shows that it has no methods.  That means there's no registerReference method, which CollaborativeString uses to keep track of cursor positions.

How frustrating.  So I guess I have to work around it.  I see a few options:

1. Ignore the fact that the cursor gets messed up during collaboration
2. Use a CollaborativeMap instead of a custom type, and wrap it with my custom type at runtime

Probably going to do option 2.

Comment: This should be possible.. can you show exactly what you are doing, and the specific error message?

Comment: If it's possible, show me how to do it.  It doesn't seem possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand how this site works, the onus is not on other people to show you how to do something - you're asking other people to take time from their day and help you.

That being said, taking a quick look at the page that you linked shows that what you want to do is not only possible but quite straightforward and compatible with bindString. Stealing from the example code from that page:

```
// Call this function before calling gapi.drive.realtime.load
function registerCustomTypes()
{
    var Book = function () { };

    function initializeBook()
    {
        var model = gapi.drive.realtime.custom.getModel(this);

        this.reviews = model.createList();
        this.content = model.createString();
    }

    gapi.drive.realtime.custom.registerType(Book, 'Book');

    Book.prototype.title = gapi.drive.realtime.custom.collaborativeField('title');
    Book.prototype.author = gapi.drive.realtime.custom.collaborativeField('author');
    Book.prototype.isbn = gapi.drive.realtime.custom.collaborativeField('isbn');
    Book.prototype.isCheckedOut = gapi.drive.realtime.custom.collaborativeField('isCheckedOut');
    Book.prototype.reviews = gapi.drive.realtime.custom.collaborativeField('reviews');
    Book.prototype.content = gapi.drive.realtime.custom.collaborativeField('content');

    gapi.drive.realtime.custom.setInitializer(Book, initializeBook);
}
```

and

```
// Pass this as the 2nd param to your gapi.drive.realtime.load call
function onDocLoaded(doc)
{
    var docModel = doc.getModel();
    var docRoot = docModel.getRoot();

    setTimeout(function ()
    {
        var book = docModel.create('Book');

        book.title = 'Moby Dick';
        book.author = 'Melville, Herman';
        book.isbn = '978-1470178192';
        book.isCheckedOut = false;

        book.content.setText("Call me Ishmael. Some years ago - never mind how long precisely - having little or no money in my purse, and nothing particular to interest me on shore, I thought I would sail about a little and see the watery part of the world.");

        docRoot.set('tbook', book);

        debugger;
    }, 0);
}
```

Good luck and have fun with the Realtime API - it's a lot of fun to play with.

Comment: Where did you find this example code?  I don't see it on the page I linked.

Comment: Hi Nick - it's spread out over page under the sections "Registering and creating custom objects" and "The Initializer". The example code they provide does not use a CollaborativeString and instead uses a CollaborativeList.

Comment: This example seems weird.  At first, it would seem like you are clobbering the collaborativeField property by putting a CollaborativeString over it.  I guess that enhances it?  I wonder why they made this system so weird that you have to clobber your fields on initialization, instead of initially declaring them as the types they should be...

Comment: Oh, I see it now.  Ok.  Well I guess if that's how we're supposed to do it.  Thank you =]

Comment: For the record, I don't find this straightforward at all, and I totally expected it to be impossible to do :P.  I already worked around it in my code, but knowing this will help me simplify things a little.

Comment: The 'collaborativeField' is just a way for the api to know how the object is laid out and which properties to pay attention to and sync. Think of the field as a slot which you can assign values - in this case you are assigning a CollaborativeString. In the other cases (title/author etc) you are setting the value to a plain string. Nothing is getting clobbered :).

This is basically implemented as JS getters and setters https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question and answer are getting old, but for reference's sake, just the last part of Grant Watters' very good answer, the onDocLoaded routine, is rather misleading. That function as written, is more suited for the 3rd parameter to the gapi.drive.realtime.load call, the onInitializeModel callback.

The 2nd parameter is called every time the Doc is loaded. You wouldn't normally add the same object over and over as the above routine would... Instead, you would normally set up your event handling, your dataBinds etc. This version might clarify somewhat:

```
// Pass this as the 2nd param to your gapi.drive.realtime.load call
function onDocLoaded(doc)
{
    var docModel = doc.getModel();
    var docRoot = docModel.getRoot();
    var text = doc.getModel().getRoot().get("text");

    // Add an event listener...
    text.addEventListener(gapi.drive.realtime.EventType.TEXT_INSERTED, onStringChanged);

    // ...and/or bind to collaborative objects:
    var textArea = document.getElementById('textArea1')
    textBinding = gapi.drive.realtime.databinding.bindString(text, textArea);

    etc...
}
```

Not incidentally, bindString returns the binding object, which is needed to "unbind" later, preventing an AlreadyBound error or other unexpected behavior when the next Doc is loaded. Do something like this:

```
function onDocLoaded(doc)
{
    // Clear any previous bindings etc:
    if (textBinding) { textBinding.unbind() };
    textBinding = null;

    etc...
```